# How to combine two arrays into a single? (React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

There are two arrays like the one below.

```
const arrayA = {
 0: {
  id: XXXXXXX,
  name: "test"
 },
 1: {
  id: YYYYYYY,
  name: "example"
 }
}


const arrayB = {
  0: {
    id: XXXXXXX,
    category: "sea",
  }
  1: {
    id: YYYYYYY,
    category: "mountain"
  }
}
```

I would like to combine these two arrays into a single one by each id like the below:

```
array C = {
 0: {
  id: XXXXXXX,
  name: "test",
  category: "sea",
 },
 1: {
  id: YYYYYYY,
  name: "example",
  category: "mountain"
 }  
}
```

What is the smartest way to do this?

Comment: I'm guessing this got downvoted because "smartest" is not a particularly actionable metric on which to evaluate answers.

Comment: Those are not array, they are objects. Search `js deep merge` on google, hope you will find your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there are not arrays but objects having keys like indexes. You can use `Object.keys` for the iteration and merge them by keys through objects.

```js
const arrayA = {
 "0": {
  id: 0,
  name: "test"
 },
 "1": {
  id: 1,
  name: "example"
 }
}


const arrayB = {
  "0": {
    id: 0,
    category: "sea",
  },
  "1": {
    id: 1,
    category: "mountain"
  }
}

const arrayC = {}

for(const key of Object.keys(arrayA)) {
   arrayC[key] = {
      ...arrayA[key],
      ...arrayB[key],
   }
}

console.log(arrayC)
```

You also can use `reduce` instead of an usual iteration

```js
const arrayA = {
  "0": {
    id: 0,
    name: "test"
  },
  "1": {
    id: 1,
    name: "example"
  }
}


const arrayB = {
  "0": {
    id: 0,
    category: "sea",
  },
  "1": {
    id: 1,
    category: "mountain"
  }
}

const arrayC = Object.keys(arrayA).reduce((result, key) => ({
  ...result,
  [key]: {
    ...arrayA[key],
    ...arrayB[key]
  }
}), {})

console.log(arrayC)
```